# Создание DOM-элементов в Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как следует добавлять новые элементы на страницу используя Jquery?Или же лучше добавлять элементы через чистый JavaScript и только потом взаимодействовать с ними через Jquery?

Comment: А сам как пытался и что именно не получается?

Comment: разницы нет, но если вы уж используете жуквери, то с ним синтаксис явно короче

Comment: не понятно именно как работает добавление элементов через JQ,в одном случае элемент перемещается,а в другом создаётся копия

Comment: @Егор, лучше так и задавать вопрос: привести код и спросить почему в одном случае работает так, а в другом так. Сам по себе jquery копию элементов не создает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз уж jQuery уже подключен, нет особой разницы.

Пример на jQuery (создание таблицы с указанным кол-вом столб-строк):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#red', function(){
  const cell = Number( $('#cell').val() );
  const row  =  Number( $('#row').val() );
  
  const table = $('<table></table>');
  for(let i = 0; i < cell; i++){
      const tr = $('<tr></tr>');
  for(let u = 0; u < row; u++){
      const td = $('<td></td>');
      tr.append(td);
    }
    table.append(tr);
  }
  
  $('#content').empty();
  $('#content').append(table);  
});
```

```css
#red {background-color: #fff1ba; border: 2px solid orange; outline:none;}

td {width: 20px; height: 10px; border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="red">Создать таблицу</button>

<input id="cell" placeholder="кол-во строк?">
<input id="row" placeholder="кол-во столбиков?">

<div id="content"></div>
```

Ровно то же самое на чистом JS:

```js
document.getElementById('red').addEventListener('click', function(){
  const cell = Number( document.getElementById('cell').value );
  const row  = Number( document.getElementById('row').value );
  
  const table = document.createElement('table');
  for(let i = 0; i < cell; i++){
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  for(let u = 0; u < row; u++){
    const td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(table);
});
```

```css
#red {background-color: #fff1ba; border: 2px solid orange; outline:none;}

td {width: 20px; height: 10px; border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<button id="red">Создать таблицу</button>

<input id="cell" placeholder="кол-во строк?">
<input id="row" placeholder="кол-во столбиков?">

<div id="content"></div>
```

В процессе можно добавить `td.addClass('class');` (jQ) или `td.className = "class";` (JS)

Или добавить контент, потом append... td.html("БУБУ"); / td.innerHTML = "БУБУ";

Единственное, рекомендуют сначала всю конструкцию за кулисами создать, и только в конце одним append-ом добавить весь элемент куда надо. Было бы не правильно создавать элементы и пихать их по отдельности в HTML на каждом шаге.